# Any possible way to save webpage state to HDD?

Tags: python, c++, browser, plugins, webkit

Essentially what I want to do is be able to click a button and have the webpage state be stored somewhere on the HDD so it doesn't need to just sit in RAM, and when it's loaded again at some later time the page pops up exactly as it was before as if it had never been closed without the need to download anything over the internet to restore it (although additional resource requests that didn't exist when the page was saved should still download properly).
(as an example, firefox does this when it crashes, all the tabs are restored, text you've typed is still in the textboxes, etc..)

I don't care if that button is in a firefox plugin, chrome, or even a custom browser that I program myself with something like webkit perhaps.

I've been trying for days to find a way to do this. I made WebKit programs in both C++ and Python but every time I think I'm getting close there is some deficiency in webkit or a build-in security measure that prevents me from doing this. I tried creating MHTML archives but they don't allow javascript to download new data over the internet, I tried pickling the entire WebKit.WebView object in python, I tried looking through webkit code to see if I could patch the behavior into the source code myself

I'm running out of ideas and the only one I see left is to just post this online. Is there any way that I can do this, in any programming or scripting language, using any libraries at all?
I just have no idea where to turn next.

Comment: Make a local proxy server that caches the pages.

Comment: this sounds awfully similar to what wget does.

Comment: afaik most browsers provide addons that already do this

Comment: @JoranBeasley, If I could find a plugin that would allow me to control saving/loading of those cached pages then that would be perfect but I haven't been able to.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, how exactly would that work? The proxy server would need to cache the page state as it currently is in my browser (i.e. caching all current javascript variables, browser history so that backward/forward buttons still work, etc.) can that be done?

Comment: so not like readfastlater?

Comment: @JoranBeasley, well do the saved pages actually get cached or do they still sit in RAM but just out of sight? It says you can archive them later, so I'm guessing it doesn't do it by default. Also, once archived and reloaded do the pages behave exactly as they would if they were never closed or do some features stop working?

Comment: no idea ... I assume they save ... and probably behave the same within reason ...  Im not sure what you are trying to do? save the internet on your harddrive ... in theory you can just click links on the pages and travel between any 2 sites on the web

Comment: sorry for the local proxy suggestion, your question too long, didn't read. but now, how about e.g. [session manager for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-manager/). that was my first google hit.

Comment: @JoranBeasley, I guess basically what I want is to have behavior exactly like that of tabs, except that the tabs would be stored on the HDD when you're not using them. It would be a way of essentially having massive amounts of tabs open but without taking up any extra resources. I know I could just bookmark the pages, but then you lose the advantages of tabs (fast switching, less requests, and sometimes tabs alert you to things). I was thinking of programming my own browser that would periodically (every 30min or so) load the page tabs from the HDD to let any scripts load new data and re-save

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, session manager looks like it has the behavior I was looking for on saving thanks for suggesting it. I wonder if I can look at their code to see how they are saving and see if I can give myself more control over it. Thanks

Comment: @spacelike: A firefox extension is usually just a zip archive with some XML (XUL user interface definitions) and JavaScript. So there should be no problem looking at the code.